# Which LaTeX IDE has Vi plugin?

Tags: editors, vim, ide

I'm looking for a LaTeX IDE which has `Vi` plugin, but I haven't found any. I tried out `vim-latex`, but I couldn't find a way to install it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What operating system are you working on? Also, there are installation instructions for Vim-LaTeX [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download).

Comment: @Werner: your link seems broken.

Comment: @Raphink: The link still works on my end. Alternatively, click [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php) to visit the Vim-LaTeX homepage, and click on download - the installation instructions are listed here as well.

Comment: @Werner Grundlingh: either Linux or Windows works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Besides the well-known `vim-latex` suite, there also is the smaller, but nice [`latex-box`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3109) plugin for vim.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) has `vim` mode, as it uses [kate](http://kate-editor.org/) as the editing component. It can be set under `Settings/Editing/Editor/Vi input mode`.

It does not support all `vim` features, but I found it good enough for what I needed (i.e. usual way to type/search/copy/move/...)

Comment: There's something ugly and clunky-seeming about Kile to me, at least on Ubuntu where I'm using it. The colour schemes come out wrong, there's a horrible sound each time a notification pops up. I'm sticking with TexStudio, hang the Vi keybindings.

Comment: Do not forget to change Input Mode to "Vi Input Mode" in Settings->Editor->Editing-General under Input Mode

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I installed the vim latex-suite on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-latexsuite

sudo vim-addons -w install latex-suite
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Martin- I wasn't sure if I should use a code block, as it wasn't TeX. I'll know for next time!

Comment: That's a lot Martin ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can now edit LaTeX documents in Visual Studio Code using the [LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) extension.

When combined with the [Vim extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim), you can edit LaTeX documents using Vim, alongside all the other perks of VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another option. Emacs with plugins evil and auctex. With this combination you can get all main features to edit latex documents with vim key-bindings